# Error while building ggplot2 book : could not find function "pandoc_latex_engine_args"

Tags: r, build, r-markdown, pandoc

I just [reported the following issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book/issues/104) to the [hadley/ggplot2-book](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book) repository:

When i press STRG+SHIFT+B in RStudio to build the book as described in the Readme I get this error:

```
mkdir -p book/tex
mkdir -p book/tex/_figures
mkdir -p book/tex/diagrams
cp book/ggplot2-book.tex book/tex/ggplot2-book.tex
Rscript book/render-tex.R data-manip.rmd
Error in rmarkdown::pandoc_options(to = "latex", from = "markdown_style",  : 
   could not find function "pandoc_latex_engine_args"
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> structure -> <Anonymous>...
```

I have `R 3.2.2`, `Rtools 3,2,x` , `pandoc 1.15.2` and installed all the dependencies as well as the `inconsolata` font. I have `MikTeX 2.9` and also updated all packages that where updatable.

When I try `?pandoc_latex_engine_args` (which presumably causes the error) the help page opens so this function should be available to R. I tried on 2 different computers (Windows 10 and Windows 7) and reran the complete installation process on each without any change. I also tried to manually build the book using the `Cygwin` terminal but this gives the same error.

Has anyone trying to build the book had the same problem or even better: does anyone know how to fix this?